# UNNotificationServiceExtension not working on iPhone 5 (iOS 10)

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am not able to intercept push notification via `UNNotificationServiceExtension` on iPhone 5 running on iOS 10.

The `mutable-content` flag is set as 1 inside the aps in payload. The same notification is getting intercepted in the extension for iPhone 6S.

Is Notification Service app extension not supported on iPhone5(because of 32-bit maybe)?

I have looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) and it is no where mentioned that it will work only on specific devices.

Asked the same [question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84035) in Apple Developer forum as well.

Comment: Check your deployment target for the extension. it should be same for test device and deployment target.

After altering the deployment target to 10.0 the UNNotificationServiceExtension instance called perfectly

Comment: The same build is working on iPhone 6S. I dont think its an issue with deployment targets.

Comment: May be your iPhone 6S device using 10.1 and match with your UNNotificationServiceExtension deployment target and iPhone 5 using lower version of deployment target.

Comment: @NikhleshBagdiya, let me test it out.

Comment: It's solve your issue

Comment: @NikhleshBagdiya: you were right. If you want you can write your comment as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your deployment target for the extension. it should be same for test device and deployment target. After altering the deployment target to 10.0 the UNNotificationServiceExtension instance called perfectly.
May be your iPhone 6S device using 10.1 and match with your UNNotificationServiceExtension deployment target and iPhone 5 using lower version of deployment target. So will not work on iPhone 5.